# Exporting a layer from QGIS to PostgreSQL

Tags: qgis, postgresql, layers

In: [How to write a (memory) layer from QGIS to PostGIS?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/108851/how-to-write-a-memory-layer-from-qgis-to-postgis), one of the the suggestions for writing a qGIS layer to postgreSQL table involves using the below code in the qGIS python console.  The code seems like a reasonable approach.  And it sometimes does work and creates a table called "test."  Mostly, it does not create a table but instead throws an error.  The code is:

```
    uri = "dbname='test' host=localhost port=5432 user='user' password='password' key=gid type=POINT table=\"public\".\"test\" (geom) sql="
    crs_id = 4326
    crs = QgsCoordinateReferenceSystem(crs_id,  QgsCoordinateReferenceSystem.EpsgCrsId)
    # layer - QGIS vector layer
    error = QgsVectorLayerImport.importLayer(layer, uri, "postgres", crs, False, False)
    if error[0] != 0:
        iface.messageBar().pushMessage(u'Error', error[1], QgsMessageBar.CRITICAL, 5)
```

This part seems as if it might indicate a path for a table in postgreSQL? 
`table=\"public\".\"test\"`. But I have not heard of using paths for postgreSQL table? And I use windows 7.  Nor I am sure about this part: `(geom) sql="`

The error is:

> ```
> Traceback (most recent call last):
>   File "<input>", line 1, in <module>
>   File "C:/Program Files/QGIS 2.18/bin/layer save selected to postgres.py", line 6, in <module>
>     error = QgsVectorLayerImport.importLayer(layer, uri, "postgres", crs, False, False)
> TypeError: QgsVectorLayerImport.importLayer(QgsVectorLayer, QString, QString, QgsCoordinateReferenceSystem,
> bool onlySelected=False, bool skipAttributeCreation=False,
> dict-of-QString-QVariant options=None, QProgressDialog progress=None)
> -> (QgsVectorLayerImport.ImportError, QString): argument 1 has unexpected type 'str'
> ```

I have tried placing the port in quotes but it did not help: `port='5432'`

Another much more involved approach, might be based on issuing commands in postgreSQL, for the qGIS python console; but this would also mean adding in the the commands to insert the values for each attribute and row for a qGIS layer, something I have not figured out.  In addition, the geometry attribute would need to be added in, yet it does not appear in the qGIS attribute table?

```
    from PyQt4.QtSql import *
    layer = iface.activeLayer()
    uri = QgsDataSourceURI()
    uri.setConnection("localhost", "5432", "your database", "user name", "password")
    uri.setDataSource("public", "table name", "geom")
    db = QSqlDatabase.addDatabase("QPSQL");
    db.setDatabaseName(uri.database())
    db.setPort(int(uri.port()))
    db.setUserName(uri.username())
    db.setPassword(uri.password())
    db.open()
    ok = db.open()
    ## below just shows that a table can be created and values can be inserted.
    query = db.exec_("""create table aaa (d INT4) """)
    query = db.exec_("""INSERT INTO aaa(d) VALUES(2) """)
```

Could I get the value for the geometry attribute like this?

```
    layer = iface.activeLayer()
    for f in layer.getFeatures():
        dGeom = f.geometry()
```

And then add in dGeom using AddGeometryColumn?

Note: This works, even if it uses a round about method:

```
    from PyQt4.QtSql import *
    from PyQt4 import QtGui
    from PyQt4.QtCore import *
    import random
    import subprocess

    polyIsHere = 0
    postgresTable = ""
    # make sure layer is there
    layer=None
    for lyr in QgsMapLayerRegistry.instance().mapLayers().values():
        lookFor = 'your_layer_name'  ## it looks for the poly one
        lookIn = lyr.name()
        mId = lyr.id()
        mYes = "" 
        if lookFor in lookIn:
            print "it's in here: " + lookIn
            polyIsHere = 1
            vl = QgsMapLayerRegistry.instance().mapLayersByName(lookIn)[0]
            iface.setActiveLayer(vl)
    if polyIsHere == 1:
        print 'forming path'
        # get info from this layer to form file name
        lyr = iface.activeLayer()
        features = lyr.getFeatures()
        for ft in features:
            attrs = ft.attributes()
        d1 = attrs[1]  
        d2 = attrs[2]  
        n = d2.partition(' ')[0]
        n3 = d2.split()[1]
        n2 = n.replace(",", "")
        dName = d1  +'_' + n2 
        layer = iface.activeLayer().name()
        layer2 = iface.activeLayer()
        short_layer = layer.split("_")[0]
        dPath = "your_path" 
        dExt = ".shp"
        file_and_path = dPath + dName +'_' +short_layer + dExt
        postgresTable = dName +'_' +short_layer
        dCRS = QgsCoordinateReferenceSystem(2229)
        file_and_path = dPath + dName +'_' +short_layer + dExt
        print 'writing shapefile'
        writer = QgsVectorFileWriter.writeAsVectorFormat( layer2,      file_and_path, "utf-8", dCRS, "ESRI Shapefile")
        # -d will delete the table if it is there
        doThis = 'C:\\PostgreSQL\\pg96\\bin\\shp2pgsql -d -s 2229 ' + file_and_path + ' > aaaa.sql  | psql -h localhost -d your_database -U postgres  -f aaaa.sql'
        os.system(doThis)    
        uri = QgsDataSourceURI()
        myPrimaryKey = "apn"                   
    uri.setConnection("localhost","5432","your_database","postgres","postgres")
        uri.setDataSource("public",postgresTable,"geom","",myPrimaryKey)
        db = QSqlDatabase.addDatabase("QPSQL");
        db.setDatabaseName(uri.database())
        db.setPort(int(uri.port()))
        db.setUserName(uri.username())
        db.setPassword(uri.password())
        db.open()
        #query = db.exec_("""select * from """ +postgresTable)
```

Comment: Are you sure `layer` is always a `QgsVectorLayer` (and not for example a layer id)?

Comment: I think you need to convert your strings to Qstrings see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1400858/how-to-create-qstring-in-pyqt4)

Comment: table=\"public\".\"test\" just escapes the " within a ".  You would probably achieve the same by just doing table='public.test'  or even table=public.test though I don't use pyQGIS so maybe not.

Comment: I can't import QSring I get the error:

Comment: from PyQt4.QtCore import QString
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<input>", line 1, in <module>
ImportError: cannot import name QString

Comment: my qGIS is version: 2.18.11

Answer (score 1):

As a work around for the qString problem, I am using `layer = qgis.utils.iface.activeLayer()`. This works and will save the table in postgreSQL. For some reason, the geometry is lost and instead becomes an incrementing integer?  Also, I don't know if there is a way to test whether or not the postgreSQL table exists?  Writing to an existing table will throw and error.

```
    dTable = "table name"
    uri = "dbname='database name' host=localhost port=5432 user='user name' password='your password' key=gid type=POINT table=" + dTable
    crs_id = 2229
    crs = QgsCoordinateReferenceSystem(crs_id, QgsCoordinateReferenceSystem.EpsgCrsId)
    layer = qgis.utils.iface.activeLayer()
    error = QgsVectorLayerImport.importLayer(layer, uri, "user name", crs, False, False)
    if error[0] != 0:
            iface.messageBar().pushMessage(u'Error', error[1], QgsMessageBar.CRITICAL, 5)
```